# Creating a subdomain that points to another server from cloudflare

Tags: domain-name-system, subdomain, cloudflare

Sorry, I'm new at this but here is my problem:

We've got a domain with godaddy the dns is with cloudflare and the site is on herokuapp.

I need to create a subdomain for the domain which points to a server with wordpress so that marketing people can create what they need fast.

How do I go about doing that?

I've seen someone just use herokuapp to host wordpress, but it doesn't seem like the best solution.

I've tried to create a cname record for the subdomain, but that just points to an empty herokuapp page.

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Just make sure that Heroku listen on that particular hostname and the hostname that you put in the CNAME is correct. The heroku documention should give you everything

Answer (score 0):

Make Heroku listen to that hostname and make sure to put the CNAME record of that domain pointed to heroku